# Is there any way to prevent Bootstrap from applying to select components?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, react-component

I'm working on a Gatsby site that uses `react-bootstrap`.

I'm trying to add search functionality using Algolia but the bootstrap theming is overriding the local theming and messing with the design of the search component.

I'm wondering if there is a way on a per-component basis to prevent the bootstrap styling from being applied other than explicitly overriding each element's CSS?

I have seen a few old questions regarding removing Bootstrap from an individual element but not regarding removing Bootstrap from individual React components. Hoping there is a simple solution.

Comment: Hi, are you using the react-bootstrap Component? or is it effecting a regular HTML <select> ?

Comment: Its regular Bootstrap, not react-bootstrap, and unfortunately I can't change that...though if it would fix the issue I can speak with those who could...